# Is this meta tag on topic & in scope?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, meta

On this meta site, we have the tags [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). These would appear to be redundant. Could we set one as a synonym of the other?

Comment: [meta-tag:scope] is the canonical name, following [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags that you mentioned are created way before people ever come up on meta (that is, by the system itself).

[on-topic](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic): To signify and figure out whether a certain genre of question is allowed.

[scope](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope): To figure out why questions are on/off-topic, why, and for discussions about including particular subjects and topics within the site.

They overlap, yes. But they're unique and their applications are broad... :)

Comment: Your definitions are correct, and synonymous. The tags should be synonymous, they are on many metas. The predefined list of meta tags was made on the quick and never fixed.